# What if you died before facing the raven?

Tags: doctor-who

In the Doctor Who season 9 episode titled *Face the Raven*, Ashidlr ( or Me) could give someone a death sentence. What if the person given that death sentence died before the countdown ended? She gives them a countdown so they can say goodbye to their families, but because it is, I presume, Time Lord technology, would it freeze you and stop your heart beat until the countdown ended like it did with Clara? Or would it, perhaps, give you some sort of protection otherwise?

Comment: The Raven was not Time Lord tech. The Doctor used Timelord Tech to pull Clara out of time.

Comment: @Moridin The question is about the timer, not the raven.

Comment: @Moridin And where did the raven come from? Who gave it to Ashildr in the first place? See [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109810/in-face-the-raven-who-gave-ashildr-the-power-of-quantum-shade-and-why).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is only speculation, but I would assume that they would just die.

In [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109810/in-face-the-raven-who-gave-ashildr-the-power-of-quantum-shade-and-why/109816#109816) I explain how the Quantum Shade is its own entity, separate to the Time Lord technology. Its power is simply granted to Ashildr by the Time Lords in exchange for her cooperation in trapping the doctor.

I would assume that the timer is simply a countdown for the Raven's victim, allowing them to know when their time is up. This would be part of the negotiation that Ashildr discussed with the Raven before it harvested the soul. Once the timer reaches zero, it can have their soul.

The timer does not hold any particularly special properties other than the fact that it holds a constant time no matter where in the universe one is. It simply counts down the minutes for that person's frame of reference (so there is no going near a black hole or to the end of the universe to stop it, for example).

Of course, we've seen other Time Lord technology override this. Clara was made to stop moving through time, which is why she had no heartbeat. This meant that the timer did not end, and thus the Raven was stalled by the terms of the contract. It could not claim the soul until the timer ran out, but as long as Clara remained locked between heartbeats and not moving through time, the Raven would be unable to collect her soul.

Thus, this would lead to three conclusions, depending on the technology of the Time Lords and how souls work. When the person with the timer dies:

1. The technology understands that that person has died, therefore the clock immediately goes to zero and the Raven can come and collect the soul.
2. The clock continues to run down as normal on the corpse (or the deceased person's soul), and when the countdown is finished the Raven collects the soul.
3. The soul can only be collected at the time of death (such as in the earlier episode with the underwater city where the souls of the deceased are used to create a distress beacon), therefore when the subject dies their soul escapes, and the Raven is robbed of a soul.

I would assume number 3, as it appears the Raven is very specific about contract negotiations, as Ashildr is unable to renegotiate with it once a third party (Clara) has offered a new contract (her own life).

My conclusion is this: **If the person dies before the time has elapsed, the Raven has not provided any service (killing the victim), therefore it would not receive the payment of its soul.**

Comment: You've got the cause/effect of Clara's heart the wrong way around.

Comment: @OrangeDog fixed. Good spot, I worded that sentence very poorly.